# Как сохранить ArrayList состоящий из объектов в sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, gson, android-shared-preferences

Я сохраняю ArrayList swedish1voc (словарь шведских слов для 1 уровня),
состоящий из стрингов, в SharedPreferences вот таким образом:

```
public void saveData() {
    Log.d(TAG, "saveData: called");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonSw1 = gson.toJson(swedish1voc);
    
    editor.putString("sw1 list", jsonSw1);

    editor.apply();
}
```

Прекрасно. А как мне сохранить ArrayList final1voc, состоящий из объектов `<Word>`?
(каждый объект - это шведское слово, его русский перевод (то есть 2 стринга) и +аудиофайл озвучки)

Т.е. в первом случае я пишу:

```
String jsonSw1 = gson.toJson(swedish1voc);
```

А во втором случае я пишу:

```
"????..." jsonFinal1 = gson.toJson(final1voc);
```

Вот что там вместо вопросов должно быть?

Comment: toJson всегда String возвращает, но SharedPreferences для хранения больших данный, используйте БД (Room)

Comment: это всмысле SQlite?

Comment: да sqlite, а room - это ORM, удобная обёртка для sqlite (опечатался в первом комменте, хотел написать: "SharedPreferences **не подходит** для хранения больших данный")

Answer (score 1):

Shared Preference не предназначен для хранения подобных штук. Shared Preference предназначен для хранения настроек приложения, каких-то простых данных вроде строковых ID объектов (и то если это не список на 1000 объектов).

Если вы хотите хранить более сложные объекты то вам нужно создавать базу данных в вашем приложении. SQLite - это БД которая работает на Android из коробки. Но она достаточно низкоуровневый инструмент, а это чревато ошибками и даже Google рекомендует [не использовать ее в чистом виде](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite). Поэтому лучше используйте [Room Database](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room?gclid=Cj0KCQjwnqH7BRDdARIsACTSAduL1ovR74d3_sK097YnmWKimIKhU6cEVw8c_8R8s9NJoT0dQTiFGTcaAq1oEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Конечно никто вам не запретит хранить в Shared Preference хоть целую базу данных. Как вариант, вы можете все ваши объекты сериализовать в строковый JSON, но вы потеряете возможность удобно работать с вашими данными. По сути это будет просто огромная строка из которой вам трудно будет достать какие-то данные выборочно.